# How to make my own ubuntu 18.04 lte with my package

Tags: 18.04, custom-distributions

I have a couple of software to be installed on ubuntu I want to run a shell script while installing Ubuntu. Please help how I can proceed.

Comment: i want it for ubuntu 18.4 .

Comment: As i was going through your link i am getting a problem "The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kamilion/ubuntu-builder/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file."

Comment: The ubuntu-builder project has been discontinued. Use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/49679/17722) instead

Comment: i am getting E: Unable to locate package dchroot while using sudo apt-get install squashfs-tools dchroot

Comment: use `schroot` instead